# XSLT 1.0 Nested Loop with condition

Tags: loops, xslt, nested

I have an input XML with headers followed by 3 details. Then the second header followed by 1 detail.

Here the expected output is 2 separate Headers.
The first header with batch name [001] have 3 DETAILS .
The second header with  batch name [002] have 1 DETAILS .
The mappings to DETAIL should continue for each Batch until the end indicator = 9.

After mapping the detail with endindicator = 9 the next header mapping will start  with another set of DETAIL.

Any thoughts to achieve this with XSL 1.0 ?

input XML as below

```
<DETAILHEADER>
  <BatchNumber>001</BatchNumber>
  <BatchItemNumber>0011</BatchItemNumber>
</DETAILHEADER>
<DETAILITEM>
  <SequenceNumber>01</SequenceNumber>
  <EndIndicator>7</EndIndicator>
<DETAILITEM>
  <SequenceNumber>02</SequenceNumber>
  <EndIndicator>7</EndIndicator>
</DETAILITEM>
<DETAILITEM>
  <SequenceNumber>03</SequenceNumber>
  <EndIndicator>9</EndIndicator>
</DETAILITEM>
<DETAILHEADER>
  <BatchNumber>002</BatchNumber> 
  <BatchItemNumber>0022</BatchItemNumber>
</DETAILHEADER>         
<DETAILITEM>
  <SequenceNumber>01</SequenceNumber>
  <EndIndicator>9</EndIndicator>
</DETAILITEM>
```

Expected output

```
<tns:HEADER>
  <BatchNumber>001</BatchNumber> 
  <tns:DETAIL>
    <SequenceNumber>01</SequenceNumber>
  <tns:DETAIL>
    <SequenceNumber>02</SequenceNumber> 
  </tns:DETAIL>
  <tns:DETAIL>
    <SequenceNumber>03</SequenceNumber> 
  </tns:DETAIL>
</tns:HEADER>
<tns:HEADER>
  <BatchNumber>002</BatchNumber> 
  <tns:DETAIL>
    <SequenceNumber>01</SequenceNumber>
  </tns:DETAIL>
</tns:HEADER>
```

I think the problem here is still not solved -  something is still wrong 
Let me be more clear with my data 
Original Input :

```
<xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="body">
<CA xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/IR_CA">
<RECORD1>
<Destination />
<Origin />
<YYMMDDHHMM>1901292353</YYMMDDHHMM>
<C6 />
</RECORD1>
<DETAILHEADER>
<BatchNumber>001</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>000</BatchItemNumber>
<Destination>175964</Destination>
<Origin>156</Origin>
</DETAILHEADER>
<RECORD6>
<BatchNumber>001</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>001</BatchItemNumber>
<CheckNumber>2332LAO54</CheckNumber>
<C8>175964</C8>
</RECORD6>
<DETAILITEM>
<BatchNumber>001</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>001</BatchItemNumber>
<Type>4</Type>
<Sequence>01</Sequence>
<EndIndicator>7</EndIndicator>
<InvoiceNumber>75040665733</InvoiceNumber>
</DETAILITEM>
<DETAILITEM>
<BatchNumber>001</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>001</BatchItemNumber>
<Type>4</Type>
<Sequence>02</Sequence>
<EndIndicator>7</EndIndicator>
<InvoiceNumber>75040665734</InvoiceNumber>
</DETAILITEM>
<DETAILITEM>
<BatchNumber>001</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>001</BatchItemNumber>
<Type>4</Type>
<Sequence>03</Sequence>
<EndIndicator>9</EndIndicator>
<InvoiceNumber>75040665735</InvoiceNumber>
</DETAILITEM>
<RECORD7>
<BatchNumber>1</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>001</BatchItemNumber>
<DepositDate>181128</DepositDate>
<RemittanceDollarTotal>0016188528</RemittanceDollarTotal>
<C8 />
</RECORD7>
<DETAILHEADER>
<BatchNumber>002</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>000</BatchItemNumber>
<Destination />
<Origin>156</Origin>
</DETAILHEADER>
<RECORD6>
<BatchNumber>002</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>001</BatchItemNumber>
<CheckNumber>2331LAZ30</CheckNumber>
<C8>220650</C8>
</RECORD6>
<DETAILITEM>
<BatchNumber>002</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>001</BatchItemNumber>
<Type>4</Type>
<Sequence>01</Sequence>
<EndIndicator>9</EndIndicator>
<InvoiceNumber>75040665731</InvoiceNumber>
</DETAILITEM>
<RECORD7>
<BatchNumber>2</BatchNumber>
<BatchItemNumber>001</BatchItemNumber>
<DepositDate>181128</DepositDate>
<RemittanceDollarTotal>0016188528</RemittanceDollarTotal>
<C8 />
</RECORD7>
<RECORD9>
<NumberofRecords>2</NumberofRecords>
<C3 />
</RECORD9>
</CA>
</part>
```

And here is the expected output- the tns namespace can be ignored

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<part xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="body">
<HEADERLP xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/HEADER">
<tns:HEADER>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>000</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:CheckNumber>2332LAO54</tns:CheckNumber>
<tns:CustomerNumber>175964</tns:CustomerNumber>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>01</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665733     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>02</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665734     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>03</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665734     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
</tns:HEADER>
<tns:HEADER>
<tns:BatchName>002</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>000</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:CheckNumber>    </tns:CheckNumber>
<tns:CustomerNumber>156</tns:CustomerNumber>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>002</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>01</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665731     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>   
</tns:HEADER>            
</:HEADERLP>          
</part>
```

But the wrong output received today

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<part xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="body">
<HEADERLP xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/HEADER">
<tns:HEADER>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>000</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:CheckNumber>2332LAO54</tns:CheckNumber>
<tns:CustomerNumber>175964</tns:CustomerNumber>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>01</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665733     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>02</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665734     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>03</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665734     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>002</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>01</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665731     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail> 
</tns:HEADER>
<tns:HEADER>
<tns:BatchName>002</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>000</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:CheckNumber>    </tns:CheckNumber>
<tns:CustomerNumber>156</tns:CustomerNumber>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>01</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665733     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>02</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665734     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>001</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>03</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665734     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>002</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>001</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>01</tns:SequenceNumber>
<tns:InvoiceNumber>75040665731     </tns:InvoiceNumber>
</tns:Detail>   
</tns:HEADER>            
</:HEADERLP>          
</part>
```

Here the detail is repeated wrongly for each header
the current code as below

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<tns:HEADERLP>
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:CA/ns0:DETAILHEADER">
<tns:HEADER>
<tns:BatchName>
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:BatchNumber"/>
</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:BatchItemNumber"/>
</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:CustomerNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:Destination"/>
</tns:CustomerNumber>
<tns:CheckNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="/ns0:CA/ns0:RECORD6/ns0:CheckNumber"/>
</tns:CheckNumber>
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:CA/ns0:DETAILITEM">
<tns:Detail>
<tns:BatchName>
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:BatchNumber"/>
</tns:BatchName>
<tns:ItemNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:BatchItemNumber"/>
</tns:ItemNumber>
<tns:SequenceNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="ns0:SequenceNumber"/>
</tns:SequenceNumber>
</tns:Detail>
</xsl:for-each>
</tns:HEADER>
</xsl:for-each>
</tns:HEADERLP>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically the detail has to be mapped only for the corresponding batch number and the mapping should stop after the endindicator = 9 has reached within DETAILITEM.

How to achieve this  with XSL version 1.0 ?

Comment: To assist with your question it is best to include what code you currently have, what version of XSLT you are using, etc.

Comment: Hi Xaviour I am trying to just to f for each for  element in input to the corresponding output element as below :

Comment: DETAILHEADER -> HEADER

Comment: DETAILITEM ->DETAIL

Comment: Both your input and your output are missing a root element. And your output has a prefix that is not bound to a namespace. Neither is allowed in XML.

Comment: I have updated the original input , expected and wrong output with the code .

Comment: Please check further

Answer (score 0):

with xsl 2.0, you can use `xsl:for-each-group`. In your case, you can use `group-starting-with`

Stylesheet is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tns="www.tns.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tns"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="DETAILHEADER">
                <tns:HEADER>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </tns:HEADER>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DETAILHEADER">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DETAILITEM">
        <tns:DETAIL>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tns:DETAIL>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have adjusted your input XML to make it well-formed. See it in action [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8R).

**XSLT 1.0**

you can use the `generate-id()` function to apply the following-siblings that has the same ID as the their first preceding-sibling `DETAILHEADER` node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tns="www.tns.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tns"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="DETAILHEADER">
                <xsl:variable name="ID" select="generate-id()"/>
                <tns:HEADER>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::DETAILITEM[preceding-sibling::DETAILHEADER[1][generate-id()=$ID]]"/>
                </tns:HEADER>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DETAILITEM">
        <tns:DETAIL>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="SequenceNumber"/>
        </tns:DETAIL>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQeV/1).

Comment: I am using XSL 1.0 - Any suggestions for 1.0 version ?

Comment: I have included an answer to comply with XSLT 1.0

Comment: A bit confusing to  understand - could please help  understand the code - and also i don;t want all elements mapped to DETAIL - but only one or chosen fields

Comment: could you please edit your question and your expected output to show what nodes should be changed to DETAIL and what nodes should not.

Comment: This is done edited the original input and output in the question

Comment: I have included an explanation here. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQeV/2

Comment: I have to still edit my input , output and the existing code - with wrong output

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do it this way (assuming a `root` root element, and ignoring the unbound `tns:` prefix on the expected output);

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="DETAILITEM" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::DETAILHEADER[1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DETAILHEADER"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DETAILHEADER">
    <HEADER>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('item', generate-id())"/>
    </HEADER>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DETAILITEM">
    <DETAIL>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SequenceNumber"/>
    </DETAIL>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```